# How do I get the length (in seconds) of audio files in a directory with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, audio, wav, duration

I need to go through a directory containing a bunch of audio files (.wav) and calculate the length, in seconds, of each file (then I'd like to have them in a .xls or .txt file ordered in column).

I found this piece of code for calculating the length of an audio file:

```
 [y,fs] = audioread(filename);
 TotalTime = length(y)./fs; % time in seconds
```

And I have this to go through a directory:

```
files = dir('directory');
for file = files'
    % get the length of the audio file, possibly by adapting the code above?
end
```

But I don't get how to put the two together. When inserting the first piece of code inside the loop (of course specifying the file name with `strcat('directory', file.name)`) I get a matrix with a single value, which I guess is the sum of the lenght of all the files.

Any tip/help? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
What I need is basically this: go into a directory, go through each audio file, get the length/duration in seconds of each file, save the value in a vector, go to the next audio file; export the final vector in a file as described above.

**EDIT 2:**
I tried this code:

```
files = dir('directory/*.wav');
i = 1
for file = files'
    [y,fs] = audioread((strcat('directory', file.name)));
    duration(i) = length(y)./fs; % time in seconds
    i = i+1;
end
```

But the vector does not contain the duration in the exact order. The duration of the second file does not correspond to the second value of the vector, neither does the third. So I guess something goes wrong.

**EDIT 3**
When I compute separately the results are congruent -- ie. if I extract y and fs from the second file and then calculate length(y)./fs, the result is correct (I manually check in Audacity the length of that file and see if corresponds to what Matlab says), same for the third and fourth file (I tried four, I have 256 of them to calculate, that's why I wanted a quick way to do it automatically). Yes, the values I obtain individually appear in the vector, but not where I expect them to be, so I think there's something wrong in the loop.

**EDIT 4**
I did as @EdR suggested and I saw that the loop went through the files like so: file 1.wav, then 10.wav, then 100.wav, 101.wav and so on (my files are numbered from 1 to 256). To avoid this is used this code:

```
for file=1:256
    audioname=sprintf('%d',file);
    audioname=strcat('directory', audioname, '.wav');
    [y,fs] = audioread(audioname);
    duration(file) = length(y)./fs; % time in seconds
end
```

Now it works and gives the correct lengths. The next step is to export this vector in a xls file: a single column with a single value in each row (until now I haven't found a way to do that).

**EDIT 5**

With the following code I solved the issue, thanks everybody! I changed `duration(file)` into `duration(file,:)` so that it stores the values in a single column (sorry, I'm new to Matlab and learn slowly what I need to solve specific problems I encounter).

```
for file=1:256
    audioname=sprintf('%d',file);
    audioname=strcat('directory', audioname, '.wav');
    [y,fs] = audioread(audioname);
    duration(file,:) = length(y)./fs; % time in seconds
end

excelname = 'filename';
xlswrite(excelname, duration);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a clearer description of what you are doing inside the loop

Comment: Inside the loop I just need to go through the directory and get the length of each audio file.

Comment: What I need is basically: go into a directory, go through each audio file, get the length/duration in seconds, save the value in a vector, go to the next audio file.

Comment: If you have a statement `A = somecalculations;` within a loop and don't index into an `A` of the correct length, all you will get out is the value of the FINAL time through the loop. Without showing us the details we can't know if this is the problem.

Comment: Do the lengths seem out of order, but correspond to one of the files? Do they correlate with your expected times i.e. longer files have bigger numbers etc?

Comment: This code should return the duration in correct order. If it does not work either you think it does not work but it does, or the data itself is not right (e.g. does the second file output a correct `fs`?).There is nothing we can do to help without the data.

Comment: If I compute separately, the results are congruent (ie. if I extract y and fs from the second file and then calculate length(y)./fs, the result is correct, same for the third and fourth file -- I tried four, I have 256 of them to calculate).

Comment: To debug the loop, try adding lines like `disp(file.name); disp(length(y); disp(fs); disp(duration(i))` Maybe you will see what is going wrong. Otherwise, as @AnderBiguri says, we can't see debug much more without your data.

Comment: Figured out what went wrong in the loop thanks to @EdR's suggestion (thanks!); I fixed it as in EDIT 4 above. I now need to export it like described.

Comment: I think the answer below should do the export you need

Comment: You do not need to add `SOLVED` to the title of your question. Accepting an answer marks it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code from edit 4, I have udpated the answer with the abilty to write an Excel file

```
for file=1:256
    audioname=sprintf('%d',file);
    audioname=strcat('directory', audioname, '.wav');
    [y,fs] = audioread(audioname);
    duration(file) = length(y)./fs; % time in seconds
end
xlswrite('duration.xls', duration.');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did next, but I checked and the second value does not correspond to the length of the second file, same for the third one. So I guess something goes wrong somewhere.

Comment: @s.gastaldon Do the lengths seem out of order, but correspond to one of the files? Do they correlate with your expected times i.e. longer files have bigger numbers etc?

Comment: As replied above, If I compute separately, the results are congruent (ie. if I extract y and fs from the second file and then calculate length(y)./fs, the result is correct, same for the third and fourth file -- I tried four, I have 256 of them to calculate, so it's not easy for me to check for correlations and correspondences, but what I think is sure is that the loop does not work properly, since individually the operations yield the correct result).

Answer (score 0):

You are well on your way I think.

```
files = dir('directory');
result = {'filename','duration(s)'}
for ct = 1:length(files)
    [y,fs] = audioread(fullfile(files(ct).folder,files(ct).name));
    result(ct+1,:) = {files(ct).name,length(y)./fs}; % time in seconds
end
xlswrite('result.xlsx',result);
```

Comment: This still goes through the directory in this order: 1.wav, 10.wav, 100.wav, 101.wav, 102.wav and so on, instead of 1.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav... (I have 256 wav files with name [progressive number].wav). But thanks for the tip on how to store the value in the vector to make it in a single column! I used that with the code in EDIT 4 and now I obtain exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: It saves it with the filename in the first column. It is easy to sort them later using excel I think, but if you want to go through them in order than your current approach is ok. You could also let matlab automatically rename the files from `1.wav` to `001.wav` ;-)

Comment: The reason I favor `dir` above generating filenames is that if you add a file (for example 257.wav) you need to change your code. Or if somebody deletes 102.wav your code crashes. It is usually safer to use `dir` and sort later.

Comment: Fair enough! In this case I'm sure no files will be deleted or added (they are stimuli for an EEG experiment), but thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind for the future!